# JDO contains filter giving illegal argument exception

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

I can't get JDO contains to work, but I can't get a good explanation on the exception on google.

Here's the code:

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(SubjectEvent.class);
            q.setFilter(":param1.contains(publisherId) && publisherType == :param2");
            q.setOrdering("created desc");
            List<SubjectEvent> events = (List<SubjectEvent>) q.execute(subjectIds, type);
```

Where publisherId and publisherType are strings and subjectIds is a ArrayList of strings.

I'm getting:

```
javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: Illegal argument
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:488)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.execute(JDOQuery.java:275)
```

Comment: james, the stack trace under that is just my function name. Nothing more. very frustrating :(

Comment: of course there is more ... called a nested exception

Comment: The same thing happening with me. The question is simple, can we pass a java.util.List as a parameter? For example "subjectIds" in @RafaelSanches original query.

Comment: I also used q.declareVariables("java.util.List param1"); but it does not help